# How can I automatically start vmware tools?

Tags: 12.04, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I'm able to run vmware tools by issuing the following command after startup:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-user
```

I'm trying to automate and have this happen when I start up.  When I place the above command in the file `/etc/init.d/rc.local` I get the following error:

```
could not open proc/fs/vmblock/dev
```

I've searched everywhere but can't find a answer.  Doing this for edX CS50

Comment: My Xubuntu VM was able to start VMTools automatically, but after upgrade to the 14.04.3 it can't do that anymore - so I have to run the `sudo /usr/bin/vmware-user` manually (which is annoying). I'd like to see a good answer to this question as well. One of answers below is for different question apparently, and another one doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Lubuntu 17.04 (Zesty):

1. Open the menu, and under **Preferences** click **Default applications for LXSession**.
2. Select **Autostart** from the pane on the left.
3. Enter `/usr/bin/vmware-user` in the **Manual autostarted applications** box, then click <kbd>+ Add</kbd>.
4. Reboot, and you should see the window at the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

You need the full path to the `.vmx` file, for example:

```
vmplayer /home/dc/vmware/Vista/filename.vmx
```

Check for yours and add it accordingly.

Comment: there is no vmx file on the linux side.  could you explain what you mean?

Comment: have to checked this ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools

Answer (score 0):

if you go into settings and click on **Session and Startup** and then click on **Application Autostart** and click <kbd>add</kbd> you can enter the command `sudo /usr/bin/vmware-user`  and that seems to do the trick.  It would be nice to understand what's going on with the `rc.local` file.  Anyone?

Comment: The solution with `Application Autostart` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install VMware tools from package `open-vm-tools` and then configure startup using `systemd`.

[Open VM tools](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803) are the currently prefered way of installing VMware tools for modern Linux distributions (including Ubuntu, of course).